# python - calculate a new column in pandas using 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe :
column header is called "Location"
example contents:
"London Arndale Centre"
"Manchester Arndale"
"Birmingham Central Station"
"Newcastle Metro Centre"

2 numpy arrays :

```
originalLocation = np.array(["London Arndale Centre","Manchester Arndale","Birmingham Central Station","Newcastle Metro Centre")

newLocation = np.array(["London","Manchester","Birmingham","Newcastle"]
```

i want to create a new column in the pandas : newLocation

the result needs to be the matching column in newLocation, where the location field matches the original location numpy.

example : "London Arndale Centre" needs to be "London"
"Manchester Arndale" needs to be "Manchester"

i have tried this , but it throw back errors

```
df['newLocation'] = newLocation[int(np.where(originalLocation == df['Location'])[0])]
```

errors : ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (159,), (12,))

what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you forgot the commas in your `originalLocation` array. Also, the `int()` is not necessary. Updated code:

```
df_data = ["London Arndale Centre", "Manchester Arndale", "Birmingham Central Station", "Newcastle Metro Centre"]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns=['Location'])

originalLocation = np.array(["London Arndale Centre", "Manchester Arndale", "Birmingham Central Station", "Newcastle Metro Centre"])

newLocation = np.array(["London","Manchester","Birmingham","Newcastle"])      

df['newLocation'] = newLocation[np.where(originalLocation == df['Location'])[0]]

df
```

Output:

```
    Location    newLocation
0   London Arndale Centre   London
1   Manchester Arndale  Manchester
2   Birmingham Central Station  Birmingham
3   Newcastle Metro Centre  Newcastle
```

**EDIT:** As you mentioned `merge` works even if not all values are included in the new locations. I create a small example using `merge`:

```
df_data = ["London Arndale Centre", "Manchester Arndale", "Birmingham Central Station", "Newcastle Metro Centre"]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns=['Location'])

originalLocation = ["London Arndale Centre", "Birmingham Central Station", "Newcastle Metro Centre"]
newLocation = ["London", "Birmingham", "Newcastle"]   

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Location': originalLocation,
                       'newLocation': newLocation})

df.merge(df_new, on='Location', how='left')
```

Output with Manchester entry missing:

```
Location    newLocation
0   London Arndale Centre   London
1   Manchester Arndale  NaN
2   Birmingham Central Station  Birmingham
3   Newcastle Metro Centre
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
this does work.
however, if i take out one of the items in df_data (eg "London Arndale Centre" and try the code i get the error message again "'Lengths must match to compare'"

how can i get the code to match even if one of the items in the match list, does not exist at source?

Comment: merge works better for me with this.

Comment: You are right! `merge` works also with missing values. I added an example to the answer for completeness.

Comment: thank you for you help.